# How to add short description in ATG Component?

Tags: atg, atg-dynamo

How to add short description for component property in ATG.
Ex: If we see loggingDebug property in a Nucleus componenet Short description will shown as `True if debug log events should be generated`. How to create such description for my property in component>

Answer (score 2):

**Simple Answer**:

You cannot add a description for an individual property.

You can add a description for a component by specifying a `$description` in the `.properties` file

**More Complex Answer**:

For viewing in the `dyn/admin` screens, each Nucleus component is associated with an *Admin Servlet*. It is the Admin Servlet of the component that renders the admin screen (not a JSP or JHTML page).

For a given component, the admin interface determines the admin servlet to use for rendering the screen by querying the component.

ATG packages a number of admin servlets with the platform. The default one is `ServiceAdminServlet` and is associated with the `GenericService`. So anything that extends from `GenericService` - most of the components you write - gets an admin screen that is rendered by ServiceAdminServlet. There is a different one for the Repository class - which is why the admin screen for a repository component looks different to that for most other components.

You can implement your own admin interface for your components by implementing your own `AdminServlet` class, and overwriting the `getAdminService()` method (defined in the `AdminableService` interface) on your component to return an instance of your custom admin servlet.

However, `GenericService` already implements the interface, and provides a convenient extensible hook method `createAdminServlet()`, and it is preferable to extend `ServiceAdminServlet` than creating your own AdminServlet from scratch.

The `ServiceAdminServlet` class defines a `printAdmin(...)` method which you override to output the custom HTML needed.

**Caveat**:

In my original answer, I had missed out the More Complex section, because I think that it is far more effort for little gain. However, I have updated my answer to be more complete.

I have been working, very hands-on, with the ATG platform since 1998, and never once have I had reason to create my own admin interface.

Comment: but when we see OOTB properties like loggingDebug description is available right. How that is implemented

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is create the MyComponentBeanInfo.java.
if you look inside the ATG_PATH\DAS\src\Java\atg\droplet, will see something like this: **Component.java** and your descriptor **ComponentBeanInfo.java**.

i have searched in oracle docs and i found this link:[Oracle Docs: BeanInfo Example](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24152_01/Platform.10-1/ATGPlatformProgGuide/html/s0503beaninfoexample01.html)

inside in your componente will be:

```
paramDescriptors[0] = new ParamDescriptor("myProperty",
                                            "this is my short description",
                                            DynamoServlet.class,
                                            false, true, outputDescriptors);

beanDescriptor = new BeanDescriptor(MyComponent.class);
beanDescriptor.setShortDescription("A custom servlet bean.");
beanDescriptor.setValue("paramDescriptors", paramDescriptors);
beanDescriptor.setValue("componentCategory", "Servlet Beans");
```